# QGIS - I have two separate attribute tables, how I combine the two?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have two separate attribute tables, one contains information about fire and the other contains the size of the forest that fire is in. The Fire IDs are different as they are data from different years. How do I add the size of the fragment that Fire is associated with to the Fire data, I want to do this over thousands of fires and fragments?

When I zoom into the fire then the associated fragment pops up.
The images show when I don't zoom in, and then when I do zoom in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you have a fire database and a forest database. What exactly do you wish as result?

Comment: @HansErren . Essentially I want each fire ID to have the forest fragment its associated with. So Fire 1, is in forest fragment size 30 for instance. I want to add that to the attribute. I am trying to see the relationship between forest fragments and fire burn area which is perimeter in this case and also see the biomes its associated with

Comment: Then the spatial join as suggested in the answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

How do you combine the attribute tables?  That depends on the data.  You could do a [Joint Attributes by Field Value](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=join%20attributes#join-attributes-by-field-value) if and only if these data share a primary key and a secondary key.  You mention that the FIDs do correlate to the records you want to join but you do not mention the other attributes.  Are there data in both tables that you can use to do a join?  Fire names, dates, coordinates?

Do the data overlap spatially?  If so, you can use the [Join Attributes by Location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=join%20attributes#join-attributes-by-location) tool.  This operation may get messy depending on how many records overlap but you could always query your data to limit the joints (for example, query data from one year in both tables before joining).  Look for Join Attributes by Location under the Vector menu - Data Management Tools.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I think I am looking for that join attributes by location you mentioned. Yes it overlaps spatially. No unfortutely there are no attributes I can join by field value. Thank you so much for this